# Text replace javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

First of all Hello to everyone, and sorry for my English.
I would still take advantage of the expertise and availability of this community.
Yesterday i see a post([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959422/get-value-of-text-inside-each-div-depending-text/22962117#22962117)) about string sostitution.
For simplicity, we remove the tables and try to look at the following code

```
<div id="find">
    <div>(this match)</div>
    <div>(this match)</div>
    <div>some text1
        <div></div>
        <div>(this match)</div>
        <div>some text2</div>
        <div>some text3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in this case if we want to find items that contain the word "match" and replace this word with "some other text" string, we can use one of these code snippet i found by reading other posts on this topic

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var elements = $('div');
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var current = elements[i];
            if(current.children.length === 0) {
               var x=current.textContent
               if (x.indexOf('match') > 0) {current.textContent='some other text'}
            }
        } 
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#find div:contains('match'):not(:has(*))").each(function () {    
         var str=$(this).text('some other text')
    })
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").each(function(){
        var str=''
        var div = $(this).clone();
        div.find("*").remove();
        str=div.text(); 
        if (str.indexOf('match') > 0) {
            $(this).text('some other text')
        }
    })
})
```

---

However, if you edit the html in this way all snippets are wrong

```
<div id="find">(this match)
    <div>(this match)
       <div>(this match)</div>
    </div>
    <div>(this match)<div>aaaa</div></div>
    <div>some text1
        <div></div>
        <div>(this match)</div>
        <div>some text2</div>
        <div>some text3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have found a solution to this problem but I think it's inelegant and overly verbose

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var len =$('#find div').length
    for(i=1;i<len;i++){
        $('div:eq('+i+')').contents().addClass('passed').filter(function () {
         return $(this).text()==='(this match)' && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length
       }).replaceWith('some other text');
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        var classx=$('div:eq('+i+')').attr('class')
        if(classx===undefined){
            var xx=$('div:eq('+i+')').contents()[0].nodeValue
            if (xx.indexOf('match') > 0) {
               $('div:eq('+i+')').contents()[0].nodeValue='some other text'
           }
        }
    }
})
```

Please could someone direct me to a more efficient and elegant way to achieve the same result?
As always, thank you all in advance, any advice will be welcomed with pleasure.

Comment: The return value of 'indexOf' is the position of the first letter your string and when the string is NOT FOUND the value returned is -1. Check your code ;)

Comment: @queval_j:Probably i have not understood your comment, but also if I write x.indexOf('match') > -1 that snippet does not work with the second html sinppet.

Comment: is not the solution, but is a problem in less.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp). If I understand what you want to do, a more "elegant" way of doing for the first snippet it could be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#find div').each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('match', 'some other text'));
    });
});
```

As for the second, this seems to work (as a caveat, it also works on the first snippet):

```
function findAllText (idToStartWith) {
    $('#' + idToStartWith).html($('#' + idToStartWith).html().replace('match', 'some other text'));
    while ($('#' + idToStartWith).text().indexOf('match') > 0) {
        $('#' + idToStartWith).find('*').each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace('match', 'some other text'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the solution for the second html code snippet.
This code is wrong.
in the second html code snippet i insert the string inside a div element that contains a div with the string

Comment: @Devima : Do you need to keep the div's event, or not ?

Comment: @Devima : if you want you can do something like that => `$('#find').html($('#find').html().replace(/\(this match\)+/gi, 'some text'));` ?

Comment: @Devima : With this "solution" you will loose all the events of your divs... But if you don't have events, it will work perfectly.